# What was changed into an immortal object?

Tags: sword-art-online

In the first arc of *Sword Art Online* (episode 14, ~9:40), the boss whom Kirito fights activates something in a system console, and then a notice is displayed: "Chaged<sup>[sic]</sup> into Immortal Object".

[image: "Chaged into Immortal Object"]

However, this message does not seem to make sense. Despite Kirito's request,

> Asuna is slain by a one-hit KO as she attempts to defend him, and Kirito is consequently killed as well. His remaining consciousness then gives one more blow to Heathcliff, who dies. Thus, it is clear that none of these three characters was given immortal status.

Was this an error, in that the message was supposed to refer to this boss *removing* his own immortality? If not, what exactly did this message signify?

Comment: It was meant to say Changed into Mortal Object, which has been corrected in the dub release.

Comment: I can confirm Dark Knight's comment, i have just watched the episode on the BluRay Release, it indeed says "Change to Mortal Object"

Comment: Wow, they spelled changed wrong. I rarely see typos like this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you say yourself:

> Was this an error, in that the message was supposed to refer to this boss removing his own immortality? If not, what exactly did this message signify?

While googling, I came across some posts on [a forum](http://forums.animesuki.com/showthread.php?t=115261&page=3) which seems to say that it is a wrongly translated message and that it should say something like: "*immortality status changed*".
I'm not sure if it's accurate but it seems to tell the exact same thing.

Comment: Also to note, in the light novel, translated by Baka Tsuki, it was translated correctly.

Answer (score 0):

That picture is false. I just rewatched that episode (episode 14 "The End of the World") and Akihiko Kayaba, or Heathcliff, is already immortal. He changed into a MORTAL object, so he and Kirito could have a fair battle. So, to answer your question, nothing was changed into an immortal object, and Heathcliff did, in fact, get rid of his own immortality. I believe the site you watched this on is a false source.

Comment: I did not watch this on a streaming site. The image is legitimate.

Comment: OP's screenshot is presumably from the TV version, whereas what you watched is likely the BD/DVD version. Commenters on the question have noted that this was apparently an error that was rectified for the BD/DVD version.

Comment: If by TV version you mean Toonami, than that's impossible because they never showed episode 14 of Sword Art Online due to their anime movie month (seeing as this episode aired in December). Akira went over SAO and they never made up for it. Some goes for an episode of Fullmetal Alchemist Brotherhood, but that's beside the point.

Comment: @DezNutzRLegendary By TV version, I mean what aired in Japan.

Answer (score -1):

It was supposed to be "Changed into immortal object" also notice the ui is RED this time.When immortal object effect was on,it was PURPLE.Thus this means something like the immortal effect is disabled.